# What Blender type should be used for custom list of objects?

Tags: python, scripting, custom-properties

Lets say I have defined a new class

```
class MyNewObject(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name = "name", default = "")
    minimum: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name = "min", default = 0.0)

    # Additional code not shown here
    # ...
    # ...
    # ...
```

Now, if I want to add an attribute storing a list of different objects (which could be a Blender `Camera`, or anything else, like another custom-defined object), what should be the `bpy.props` to use?

Comment: I would use either [bpy.props.EnumProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty) for general lists of "anything", or [bpy.props.EnumProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty) for objects, especially if they need to be defined by the user.

Comment: @L0Lock Good to know, thank you

Comment: I noticed in my previous comment I wrongly inserted the second link, it was supposed to be CollectionProperty x) but @Mr A's answer explains better anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a `bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=MyNewObject, name="Insert Name Here")`. The type parameter should match your class name. You can check [the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.CollectionProperty) for more information.

---

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, `bpy.props.PointerProperty` is also an option. [This](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.PointerProperty) is its entry in the docs. There is also [this example](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#propertygroup-example) and [this example](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#collection-example) which show how to use them. As you can see, the first is used when you just want one instance of your custom property, and the second is used when you have more than one.

Comment: What would the advantage(s)/disadvantage(s) of a `bpy.props.CollectionProperty` be with respect to the comment of @L0Lock here above?

Comment: enum props store strings when pointer property / collection property stores the adresse to actual objects

Comment: @aheuchamps As @Gorgious said, `bpy.props.EnumProperty` is incompatible with your custom `bpy.types.PropertyGroup`. Your options are `bpy.props.PointerProperty` and `bpy.props.CollectionProperty`. I will update my answer to include it.